# What does "hennaiatsu" actually mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

I don't know how it is written, but it was subtitled as "she's weird". For context: It was thought by one character after seeing another essentially tell others to go away so she could sleep in class.

I could only find definitions for "hen" and "atsu". "Hen" could mean "strange", and "atsu" could be a shortening of "atsukamashi",  which means "impudent"/"shameless".

With "nai" in the middle, the closest I can come up with is "not just strange, but shameless", but I'm super iffy on that.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Japanese.SE!  I see a lot of downvotes, but I think your confusion is perfectly understandable, so I don’t think the downvotes are really warranted.  In connected speech, や sounds almost the same as いあ.  On average the rhythm would be a bit different, though, with いあ being longer, and it’s possible to pronounce い and あ in separated fashion but it’s not really possible for や.  Your other big clue is simply linguistic knowledge, because the set of words we know is possible helps shape what we hear.  That will come with time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be parsing what you heard incorrectly. From the context you've provided I would reckon what was said was 「変【へん】な奴【やつ】」, which in the context you provided means "She's weird," and more generally means "(a person) is weird." 奴 is a vulgar/informal/derogatory way of referring to any person or object.

Comment: So 変な (hen'na) would mean strange and 奴 (yatsu) would mean person? That makes much more sense! Thank you!